# I've tried it all, but I can't import my Swift file to my Objective-C file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I've read though multiple threads on this on StackOverflow, and I can't seem to find the answer to my problem. My folder hierarchy is like this:

`"Project Name"
    - "Helpers"
        "FileIWantToImport.swift"
        "FileIWantToImportTo.m"`

I have:

- Set the build settings to have a Product Module Name `FMB`
- Set `Defines Modules` to `YES`
- a bridging header created by Xcode
- cleaned my build
- `#import FMB-swift.h` in my AppDelegate with out any problems
- Added `@objc` to my class declaration in my file so it says `@objc class MyClass: NSObject`

HOWEVER. I cannot, for the life me, figure out why it won't import into `FileIWantToImportTo.m`

I have tried:

- `#import "FMB-swift.h"`
- `#import "Helpers/FMB-swift.h"`
- `#import "Product Name/Helpers/FMB-swift.h"`
- `#import <FMB-swift.h>`
- `#import <Helpers/FMB-swift.h>`
- `#import <Product Name/Helpers/FMB-swift.h>`

All I get is `"file not found"` error. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I've looked through all the other threads and the apple docs and can't figure it out. I'm running in Xcode 7 and 10.11 GMs if that makes a difference.

EDIT: Here is an example project https://github.com/Aghassi/Example-Project

Comment: Does the bridging header file actually exist in your project?

Comment: Yes it exists in the Helpers folder since that is where the first swift file (and the only one I have currently) was created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

1. Create a Swift file in your ObjC based project. No need to create bridging headers, since they're used to see ObjC code from swift, not swift code from ObjC.
2. In your Target, under Build Settings set `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` to Yes

[image]

3. Your Swift file should have an @objc public class.

   ```
   @objc public class Example: NSObject {
       public func printSomething(text: String) {
           print(text);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Check your Project's name, and in your .m file, add `#import <ProjectsName-Swift.h>`, and you should be able to instantiate your class defined in the Swift file, and all it's public methods. You might need to build your project before importing the -Swift.h file.

Here's an example project with an ObjC class using Swift code: https://github.com/lucaslt89/Example-Project.git

Comment: All of the above have been tried, and none of them solved my issue. Let me whip up an example project if I can and post it.

Comment: I made a pull request to your repo where I added the Swift file to work with ObjC. As a side recommendation, never use spaces for project name (I also fixed that in your project).

Comment: Ok. I see that it works. What do I do about my existing project that already has spaces in the name? Renaming it seems to cause a lot of issues (the app has a today widget extension). Is there a simple non destructive way around this?

Comment: In that case, your Swift generated header will have an underscore instead of the space: `#import "Example_Project-Swift.h"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89476/discussion-between-david-and-lucaslt89).